# Scrolling div's when overflow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, html, vertical-scrolling

I have made the list of the scrolling divs with jquery UI slider funct.

See the code http://jsfiddle.net/fvtV9/7/  (updated code)

The preblem exists in the first and the last one.

The first one not scrolling enough to show all the text in content

The problem with the last is obvious, the scroller should not be there at all.

The height and width of the divs with class `.newsarticle` should be fixed width and height as in CSS.

How would you accomplish this?

Comment: Thank you for helping to educate myself. I did it http://jsfiddle.net/fvtV9/11/

Comment: Please turn your comment into a real answer below. You can mark it as accepted after two days. That will make the question go away from the Unanswered Questions tab.